# QLPreviewController does not show word document

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to open a Word Document using QLPreviewController. The document is of kind: Microsoft Word 97 - 2004 document but when I QLPreviewController it just displays the files title with "Microsoft Word 97-2004 document" right bellow.

When I try to call canPreview() it returns true but then it shows no content. Has any one else encountered this where QLPreviewController says it can preview an item but then it just doesn't show any content?

Comment: Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com. Does this occur with all documents or just one? Where do you open the document from?

Comment: Only some word documents, everything else works just fine (images, pdf, video). After a little digging I see that in the compatibility report in Word the troubled documents have a warning: "Word 6.0/95 compatibility option are set" After fixing that warning the content is than shown.

Comment: Ok. Indeed I believe only Word 97 and later are supported (canPreview only checks the file extension; only when actually parsing the document does it realize it’s an old document)